# Initializing a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, initialization, jframe

This is probably an easy question, but hey, i'm a beginner.

So I've created a program that calculates some stuff, and it's running in the console at the moment. I decided to add a user interface to it, so i created a JForm using the built in features in NetBeans IDE (probably just temporary until i learn to handle Swing manually, i have a deadline so i want to finish it fast), and draw out a few controls and containers. Now that the form is ready, how do i initialise it? As far as i know i need to call the class from Main.java somehow, correct? I've tried just doing: GUI gui = new GUI(); (the class is called GUI), but that doesn't do anything. If i leave it blank it does the same thing. Or is it suppose to initialize itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
GUI gui = new GUI(); 
gui.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Well this is embarassing, just missed that line. Thanks!

Comment: Everybody (even pros, whom I am not) makes mistakes, so don't sweat it.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO recommended way to do this is (using event dispatch thread and simple anonymous class):

```
// effectively the same as SwingUtilities.invokeLater
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        JFrame frame = new GUI(); // GUI gui = new GUI() as well
        // default value JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

From Java API http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading:

> "In general Swing is not thread safe.
>   All Swing components and related
>   classes, unless otherwise documented,
>   must be accessed on the event
>   dispatching thread."

You can use SwingUtilities.invokeLater or EventQueue.invokeLater with **same** result, i.e. SwingUtilities.invokeLater method just calls EventQueue.invokeLater method.

More information at [Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) (especially why to use that JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplest example to create a JFrame:

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("");
frame.setTitle("Welecome to JFames!");
frame.setSize(600, 400);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The `frame.setTitle("text");` command will change the frame title.

The `setVisible(boolean)` command will make it visible because it's hidden by

The `setSize(int, int)` command will change the size of the frame.

For more JFrame examples, check out for example: https://javatutorial.net/swing-jframe-basics-create-jframe

Answer (score 0):

initialize the class scope with, setTitle("Your Title");

Answer (score 0):

The above answer "initialize the class scope with, setTitle("Your Title");" says how to set the window title for a jframe.